# How do I make page_action appear for a specific page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm unfamiliar with Javascript and have been struggling to understand how I'd go about displaying the page_action icon when a specific URL is opened in a tab.

I've attempted to use some of the samples provided by Google to find specific letters in the URL (their example uses 'g'). I even tried simply using their extension unpacked and it didn't work for me when I visit Google.

```
// Copyright (c) 2011 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

// Called when the url of a tab changes.
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  // If the letter 'g' is found in the tab's URL...
  if (tab.url.indexOf('g') > -1) {
    // ... show the page action.
    chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
  }
};

// Listen for any changes to the URL of any tab.
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
```

Am I missing something incredibly obvious?

Comment: Are you talking about this example: http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/pageAction/pageaction_by_url/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [example](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/pageAction/pageaction_by_url/) is not working for me either. I contacted the author of this example and got this response:

> The URL below is a link to the trunk documentation, which has been
>   updated to reflect some new features that landed on trunk. But these
>   features aren't in the stable (or beta) channels yet, so that's why
>   the sample doesn't work there.

To fix it, create simple html page (name it `background.html`) that only loads javascript:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src='background.js'></script>
 </head>
<body>
</body>
```

Then, change one line in the `manifest.json`, from:

```
"background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
```

to:

```
"background_page": "background.html",
```

Remember to reload your extension in a browser after these changes.

That will not only work but also will allow you to debug your code:

1. Go to chrome://settings/extensions
2. Expand options of your extension
3. Click `background.html` to debug it

Comment: I had it originally setup as inline javascript in background.html and the manifest already had `"background_page": "background.html"` in it.

Comment: You probably got some older version of this example then. Current version + change described in my answer above work fine for me. It's hard to tell what is wrong with your version. The javascript part is the same as mine. Try to debug `background.html` (as described above) and see if you get some errors in console.

Comment: I took other version of this extension from here: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html#chrome.pageAction . And it works just fine.

Comment: Okay after some fiddling it seems to have been a lack of the using `"permissions": ["tabs"],` in manifest.json. Super thanks for helping me out!